# How do I make my switch statment loop properly?

Tags: c, if-statement, switch-statement, do-while

When the characters A B or C are entered it returns their numerical value.

The Default statement prints if anything is entered for the first time.
THEN if you enter A B or C it prints properly but after that the Default statement prints no matter what.

```
/*#define_USE_C99_MATH*/
/*#include <stbool.h>*/
#include <stdio.h>

main ()
{
    int ABC;     /* I/O */
    char c1 = 'A'; /*Characters to be entered*/
    char c2 = 'B';
    char c3 = 'C';

    /*typedef enum { false, true } bool;*/
    printf("Please enter either A, B, or C (case sensitive):");
    ABC = getchar();
    /*bool loop = true;*/

    if ((ABC = getchar()) == c1 | c2 | c3)
    {
        do
        {
            switch (ABC)
            {
            case 'A':    
                printf("The numerical value of A is: %d\n", c1);
                break;

            case 'B':    
                printf("The numerical value of B is: %d\n", c2);
                break;  

            case 'C':    
                printf("The numerical value of C is: %d\n", c3);
                break;  

            default:
                printf("The character you have entered is not valid.\n");
                break;
            }
        } while ((ABC = getchar()) != c1 | c2 | c3);
    }
    else
    {
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One idea: `((ABC = getchar()) == c1 | c2 | c3)` --> `((ABC = getchar()) == c1 | ABC == c2 | ABC == c3)`

Comment: Much cleaner. I will try that out. Should i do it for both?

Comment: @chux Now it immediately ends my code when I input anything.

Comment: I think it might also getting either the `\n` or the  `\0` character with `getchar()`. that's why it's running the second loop. not sure though....very new to C. try putting a case for both of these to see what it is.

Comment: @munircontractor Its not the '\n' :/

Comment: @stetdawg did you try `\0`?

Comment: I have a question. Why are you using getchar() twice for value of ABC, right after the first one?

Comment: You call `ABC=getchar();` and the immediately overwrite the value with `if ((ABC = getchar()) == c1 | ABC == c2 | ABC == c3)` so the first character is lost.  You probably didn't mean that.  And are you intentionally using bitwise or (`|`) instead of logical or (`||`) because normally with characters you want logical or like this: `((ABC = getchar()) == c1 || ABC == c2 || ABC == c3)`

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I didnt know the `getchar()` would overwrite. And i knew the difference between bitwise and logical I just didn't cross my mind for some reason. Thank you! But it didnt fix the problem.

When i use `((ABC = getchar()) == c1 || ABC == c2 || ABC == c3)` my code ends the second i input something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error seems to be that you have entered an if statement which will work only if you enter 'A' 'B' or 'C'. In  my opinion though, i think it would be better to not use if statements in this program. Rather, just keep the do while loop and the code will run fine.

Comment: Yes, this does work but what i was trying to do with that if statment was loop the switch back around so when any character but A, B or C was entered the program would say "Please enter a valid character" and then the user could input again.

Comment: So for that, you can put only an if statement for when the values entered are A, B or C. For all other cases, put an else statement.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using logical-OR `||` instead of the bitwise-OR `|` (*you can still use `|` in this case but it helps the code be more readable*). And you can encounter a problem with using input functions because when the user enters an input via `getchar()` it actually sends 2 characters, say `A` and `\n` so you need to consume the newline again via `getchar()`

I've modified your code here, but it still does the same behavior:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main ()
{
    char ABC;
    char c1 = 'A';
    char c2 = 'B';
    char c3 = 'C';

    printf("Please enter either A, B, or C (case sensitive):");
    ABC = getchar();

    while(ABC != c1 && ABC != c2 && ABC != c3)
    {
        getchar(); // Consume \n
        printf("The character you have entered is not valid.\n");
        ABC = getchar();
    }

    switch (ABC)
    {
    case 'A':    
        printf("The numerical value of A is: %d\n", c1);
        break;

    case 'B':    
        printf("The numerical value of B is: %d\n", c2);
        break;  

    case 'C':    
        printf("The numerical value of C is: %d\n", c3);
        break;  
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just remove the if statement, because if you do that you will have a chance to have your default case be true, another reason why you may be having errors is due to this:

`while ((ABC = getchar()) != c1 | c2 | c3);`

make it into:

`while ((ABC = getchar()) != c1 | ABC != c2 | ABC != c3);`

Comment: The condition is incorrect it should be `!=`, and this statement would call `getchar()` thrice which is probably not the OP wanted.